# Get all attributes from model

Tags: javascript, angular

I try to list all attibutes from a model class define in my angular app.

Here is an example of my model.

```
export class BiduleList {
  config: {
    attribute01: string;
    attribute02: number;
  }
  configuration: {
    trululu: {
      attribute03: string;
      attribute04: number;
      attribute05: number;
      attribute06: number;
    }
  }
}
```

I need to loop over all the attributes to build a form to define the associated data.

So I need to keep the layout, i.e. have the information that `attribute03` is contained in `trululu` itself contained in `configuration`

Here is an example of what I want to build from this information :

```
public configurationTrululu: { [key: string]: QuestionBase<any> };

this.configurationTrululu = {
  attribute03: new InputQuestion({
    questionContainerClass: FORM_FIELD_COL_FULL,
    textLabel: "attribute03",
  }),
  attribute04: new InputNumberQuestion({
    questionContainerClass: FORM_FIELD_COL_FULL,
    textLabel: "attribute03",
  }),
  attribute05: new InputNumberQuestion({
    questionContainerClass: FORM_FIELD_COL_FULL,
    textLabel: "attribute03",
  }),
  ...
}
```

If possible I would like to avoid having to define all attributes in a constructor like this:

```
constructor() {
  this.config = {
    attribute01 = '',
    attribute01 = 0
  };
}
```

PS: After a question in comment

when I define a `new BiduleList();` like that :

```
public biduleList: BiduleList = new BiduleList();
```

`biduleList` is empty and I can't extract all attribute from him. When I display the result of `Object.entries` in console :

```
console.log('biduleList', this.biduleList);
>>> biduleList > BiduleList

console.log('entries', Object.entries(this.biduleList));
>>> entries >Array(0)
```

PSS: I know that in PHP for example you can use the `get_class_vars` or `get_object_vars` function

Here an example : https://onlinephp.io/c/d419d

Comment: Have you tried `Object.entries`, `Object.values` and `Object.keys`, also `for..in` and `for..of`?

Comment: Hello, yes I try I edit my post to add your information

Comment: I don't see where you add properties to this class. I see only the type declaration

Comment: My BiduleList model is very large with many attributes.
I have a model and I want to be able to retrieve information from this model without having to declare my object entirely.

Comment: No, you have to assist variables, TypeScript doesn't work in runtime

Answer (score 1):

You need create an object with values. As you're working with classes you can

```
export class Fool{
  name:string;
  group:{
    op1:number;
    op2:number;
  }
  schema(){
    const fool=new Fool();
    fool.name='';
    fool.group={op1:2,op2:3}
    return Object.keys(fool)
  }
```

And use

```
schema=new Fool().schema();
```

You can also in constructor of your class create an object with default values

```
  constructor(){
    this.name='';
    this.group={op1:2,op2:3}
  }
```

And create an object and iterate over the Object.keys

```
 fool=new Fool();
 schema=keys(this.fool)
```

Comment: So there is no possibility to have this information without initializing it in the object? As I explain my object is very large and I wanted to avoid having to double the declaration with a solution like you propose.

Comment: I'm afraid than not (you can give values to the properties of the classes in the declaration and forget the "constructor", but I'm not pretty sure if can help you). Someone suggest about interfaces but I can not remember the link